# struts 2 list iteration

Tags: spring, struts2

I am new struts I have a frontend using struts and a backend using spring dao with entity types pojo class, I want to return a list of students in system.code I have tried is attached below I am getting the values only if I set the list to form class.

```
public class Studentform {
    private StudentEntity student;
    public StudentEntity getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(StudentEntity student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
    public void setStudent(ArrayList<StudentEntity> studentList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.studentList=studentList;
    }
}
```

action class code to acessslist is as studform.setStudent(studentList);

```
public class StudentAction extends ActionSupport implements
    ModelDriven<Studentform> {
    ArrayList<StudentEntity> studentList=new ArrayList<StudentEntity>();
    //geters and setter for studentList
        public String stdus() {
        HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();
        String id = (String) session.getAttribute("userid");
        studentList=controller.getStudentProfile();
        studform.setStudentList(studentList);
        System.out.println(studentList.size());
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Comment: i would like to know  why i cant iterate the list if i didnt set it in setstudent(list)

Comment: yes i need an answers

Comment: Imagine you have a Empty Box for candies, Now can you count candies without actually filling that box with candies one by one or by pack?

Comment: if you want to get List without setting second list setter method you have to add your student to your arraylist, like in your setStudent(Student student) method (studentlist.add(student)).

Comment: your action class doesn't implement `ModelDriven` interface.

Comment: i have implemented the modelDriven interface @Roman C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get Studentlist without using second method `(setStudent(ArrayList<StudentEntity> studentList))`
you have to add your student to your arraylist in your first method like `studentList.add(student);` something like this;

```
public class Studentform {

private StudentEntity student;
private List<StudentEntity> studentList = new ArrayList();

public StudentEntity getStudent() {
    return student;
}
public void setStudent(StudentEntity student) {
    this.student = student;
    studentList.add(student);
}
//add your list getter method here
```

Comment: while loading  jsp i have a similar code like this StudentEntity student1 = new StudentEntity(patern, "", "", "", "", "",
    1, "", "", 1234567891, "");
studform.setStudent(student1); if i convert the code as above it  will throw an exception in this line

Comment: show us your action class(controller) and jsp (view) with your exception so we could help you

Comment: the above code is for registering student -i need to load may jsp(register) with default values as metioned if i change the code as above i could not load my registeration page ,but view of student details without setting to list will work.

Comment: added the action class code in question  as follows and if i set a studentlList in action class what is need of setting list in form class @Boldbayar .